# Faster to manipulate existing HTML or removing the HTML and then recreating it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, repaint, dom-manipulation

This project I am working on, I have a list of elements and convert them into a "graph" (not a true graph, but you can call it a psuedo one).  I have my data set, i run a `for` loop over the data and then create a `li` element for each one, create and parent `ul`, append the `li`s and then append the parent to another DOM element (we'll call it grandparent) already on the page.  After that, i have to make subsequent updates to that list based on user interaction.
Also, this is all in the context of using jQuery.

Now, my question is - is it faster to create the elements once then update the resulting HTML on each subsequent call or is it faster to just recreate each element, `empty()` the grandparent element (which would get rid of the parent `ul`) and then reappend the newly created `ul` (which I am doing now)?

Keep in mind that when I am recreating the `li`s, they are not in the DOM at all so there is no repaint/reflow while recreating them.  The repaint only happens when I reappend the newly created `ul`.

I was speaking to a coworker and he said it would be better to just update the HTML elements once they are created rather than recreating them every single time.  i was thinking of going this route, but then I thought that updating the existing `li`s would actually cause a repaint on say 50 elements versus just doing one massive one with the `empty()` then reappending the newly created `ul`.

thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [rsp says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205228/faster-to-manipulate-existing-html-or-removing-the-html-and-then-recreating-it/5205263#5205263), you'll need to profile your solutions, as which will be fastest depends both on the structure of your markup and on the particular browser its running on.  It's also, of course, only worth going through all this effort if you're unhappy with the speed you're currently getting!

There are three basic approaches, however, each of which *could* be the fastest.  The first only causes a single repaint; the others only two, if you choose your parent node well.

1. Construct your new content as HTML strings (`[...].join("")`), then apply with `.html()`.  ***Pros:*** typically faster than method #2.  **Cons:** not necessarily by much, can leave stale jQuery data/events (i.e. can leak, if you aren't careful).
2. Construct your new content with jQuery **outside the document** (e.g. put all your `<li>`s into a `<ul>`, then insert the `<ul>` into the document after construction is complete), then insert normall.  ***Pros:*** tends to be easier to read than method #1.  **Cons:** performs worse the more complex your markup gets.
3. Remove the existing nodes from the document (ideally, a single parent node, like the `<ul>`), make your changes, then reinsert them. ***Pros:*** may be clearer and more performant than method #2, especially on complex markup.  **Cons:** becomes much more complex if the number of elements changes between renderings.

The last one only causes two repaints even though you're making a large number of changes, because only the initial removal and final insert affect the document.  Changing elements outside the document doesn't cause repaints.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest profiling your code first. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @dtan: Yes. There is no obvious answer to your question because it depends on the amount and structure of data that you have and even on the usual patterns of its manipulation. Your coworker says that it would be better to do it differently. But is it bad the way you do it? The chances are that both of those techniques would work just fine and it doesn't really matter if it takes 1 or 5 or even 50 milliseconds. And if it doesn't really matter then consider using method that you will be most comfortable maintaining in the future. Optimize for maintainability first would be my suggestion.